# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...f1720","tarball":"htt' laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm-install

how to fix this error? i'm already installed the `php artisan ui vue --auth` but i can't run this command, `npm install`, and i get this error.

> $ npm install
>   npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is
>   npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x l
>   npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
>   npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to fsevents 2 with mass
>   npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
>   npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...6","nib":"1.0.1"},"bi'
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Wahidin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-21T04_03_08_102Z-debug.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[look similar github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072#issuecomment-345555468)

```
npm cache clean --force
```

try it.

Comment: npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

if try this command,

Comment: i change my version of nodejs and that's work.